# Rank database elements python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a snippet dataset of chemical elements shown below

[image: snippet of data]

I want to create a new field called "abundance_rank", where a rank of 1 refers to the highest abundant value (Referring to 'Abundance in Earth's crust' column)

For  example,  (symbol,  abundance_in_earth_crust)  with rows  (A,  100),  (B,  100),  (C, 100),   (D,   50),   the   expected   records   of   (symbol,   abundance_in_earth_crust, abundance_rank) will be (A, 100, 1), (B, 100, 1), (C, 100, 1), (D, 50, 4). Note that the abundance_rank of D is 4.

I created a new field abundance_rank with the code below

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('chemicals.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('ALTER TABLE chemicalElements ADD COLUMN abundance_rank INTEGER')
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RANK()` analytic function would seem to be what you want here:

```sql
SELECT Symbol, abundance,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY abundance DESC) AS abundance_rank
FROM elements
ORDER BY abundance_rank DESC;
```

Your Python code might look like this:

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('chemicals.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = """SELECT Symbol, abundance,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY abundance DESC) AS abundance_rank
FROM elements
ORDER BY abundance_rank DESC"""
for row in cur.execute(sql):
    print(row)
```

Comment: i see! How would i do this as a python code?

Comment: @MsY Check the updated answer for a Python snippet which uses the select query I am suggesting.